# Mongoose query promise in function make code became ugly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I was creating my users API, I want to check if username had been used.
So I wrote a static function

```
 static findByName(name) {
   const query = User.where({
     username: name,
   });
   query.findOne((queryErr, user) => {
     if (queryErr) {
       console.log(queryErr);
       return false;
    }
    return user;
   });
 }
```

when I called it in signUp

```
signup(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Bad Request' });
  }
 if (!Users.findByName(req.body.username)) {
   return res.status(409).json({ success: false, message: 'Username has been used' });
 }
  const hashedPassword = this.genHash(req.body.password);
  const newUser = User({
    username: req.body.username,
  });
}
```

findByName return Undefined.
Finally I use promise.

```
 signup(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Bad Request' });
  }
  return Users.findByName(req.body.username).then((existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(409).json({ success: false, message: 'Username has been used' });
    }
    const hashedPassword = this.genHash(req.body.password);
    const newUser = User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: hashedPassword,
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    return newUser.save().then((user) => {
      res.json({ success: true, user });
    }).catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
     res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
   });
 }
```

That is really horrible code.
Is there better way to clean the code?

Comment: Which version of node and mongoose?

Comment: mongoose: 4.11.4
node.js: 6.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there better way to clean the code

Yes. I am going to assume `/signup` is defined as a `POST` route on the usual Express `app` instance

With that said you, since you are already using promises, you can go a step further and use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which is enabled by default in Node.js v7.6+.

This will make your code read more synchronously:

```
 async signup(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Bad Request' });
  }

  try {
    const existingUser = await Users.findByName(req.body.username)
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(409).json({ success: false, message: 'Username has been used' })
    }

    const hashedPassword = this.genHash(req.body.password);
    const newUser = await User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: hashedPassword,
      email: req.body.email,
    }).save()

    res.json({ success: true, newUser });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
 }
```

You may have noticed the use of `try/catch`. This is because since we are not using `.catch()` and we still have to handle any error that occurs. To further clean up to code, we can write an error handler middleware that will take care of errors for us:

`src/middleware/error-handlers.js`

```
// Wraps the router handler, catches any errors, and forwards to the next middleware that handles errors
exports.catchErrors = action => (req, res, next) => action(req, res).catch(next);

// Notice the first parameter is `error`, which means it handles errors.
exports.displayErrors = (error, req, res, next) => {
  const err = error;
  const status = err.status || 500;
  delete err.status;
  err.message = err.message || 'Something went wrong.';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    delete err.stack;
  } else {
    err.stack = err.stack || '';
  }

  res.status(status).json({
    status,
    error: {
      message: err.message,
    },
  });
};
```

Now we just need to `use` our error handlers:

`app.js`

```
const { catchErrors, displayErrors } = require('./middleware/error-handlers')

// Whenever you defined the function, needs to have the `async` keyword
async function signup(req, res) { ... }

// Wrap the function call
app.post('/signup', catchErrors(signUp))

// Handle any errors
app.use(displayErrors)
```

Using the above middleware transforms our code to:

```
async signup(req, res) {
  const error = new Error()

  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    error.status = 400
    error.message = 'Bad Request'
    throw error
  }

  const existingUser = await Users.findByName(req.body.username)
  if (existingUser) {
    error.status = 409
    error.message = 'Username has been used'
    throw error
  }

  const hashedPassword = this.genHash(req.body.password);
  const newUser = await User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: hashedPassword,
    email: req.body.email,
  }).save()

  res.json({ success: true, newUser });
}
```

You can see how the code is much easier to read without all the noise.

Be sure to read up on:

- [Writing middleware for use in Express apps](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)
- [Express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: Such great answer, I must need to learn how to user async/await. Thanks.
My teammate told me "always use LTS version for production is better".
Francisco, how do you think?

Comment: Well 8.0 is the next scheduled LTS starting October so you can take advantage of it now https://github.com/nodejs/LTS

Answer (score 0):

I can't test that my solution actually works (probably not) or that I'm covering every functionality of your original code. What I tried to do is to make functions that handle specific things, then chain them together, so that you can see a more clear flow of the program.

```
signup(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Bad Request' });
  }
  const handleError = error => res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  const handleExistingUser = existingUser => {
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ success: false, message: 'Username has been used' });
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
  }
  const handleCreateUser = () => {
    const hashedPassword = this.genHash(req.body.password);
    const newUser = User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: hashedPassword,
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    return newUser.save().then((user) => {
      res.json({ success: true, user });
    });
  };

  // the flow of the program is hopefully more clear here
  return Users.findByName(req.body.username)
    .then(handleExistingUser)
    .then(handleCreateUser)
    .catch(handleError);
 }
```

If you handle the error of the inner and outer promise the same, then I think it's enough to have the error handling in the outer layer. (In your last example.) But I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `undefined`, because it does not have a `return` statement. The `return user` statement, is the (useless) return value for the `findOne` callback function, not for `findByName`.

If you go for promises, then define the function as follows:

```
static findByName(name) {
    return User.where({ username: name }).findOne().exec();
}
```

And your promise chain can be simplified a bit, like this:

```
signup(req, res) {
    function report(message, status = 200) {
        res.status(status).json({ success: status === 200, message });
    }

    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
        return report('Bad Request', 400);
    }
    Users.findByName(req.body.username).then((existingUser) => {
        return existingUser ? null // treat this condition in the next `then`
              : User({
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: this.genHash(req.body.password),
                    email: req.body.email,
                }).save().exec();
    }).then((user) => {
        return existingUser ? report(user) 
                            : report('Username has been used', 409);
    }).catch((err) => {
        report('Internal Server Error', 500);
    });
}
```